# Repeated Oh My Zsh brew plugin warnings

Tags: terminal, homebrew, plugins, zsh

I keep seeing this warning every time I open an new shell on one of my machines:

```
 Oh My Zsh brew plugin:

  With the advent of their 1.0 release, Homebrew has decided to bundle
  the zsh completion as part of the brew installation, so we no longer
  ship it with the brew plugin; now it only has brew aliases.

  If you find that brew completion no longer works, make sure you have
  your Homebrew installation fully up to date.

  You will only see this message once.
```

Message keeps coming back even though it threatens that "you will only see this message once."

Thoughts on how to 'fix' this?  It [appears to be triggered](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/brew/brew.plugin.zsh) by `mkdir` being aliased?!?

Comment: Where does `zsh -x` (or maybe `zsh -x -l`) show that code being run from?

Comment: Didn't know about the `-x` flag. That led me to the culprit which was specifically specifying the `brew` plugin in my `zshrc` file. Removed it and now all is well. I'll delete this post in a few days (if I remember) unless you want to draft an answer in which case I'll give you a gold star.  thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zsh -x` (or maybe `zsh -x -l` if the code comes from a rc file read only during a login session) enables tracing; this verbose output can then be used to find where exactly the message comes from.

```
% zsh -x 2>searchthroughthis.txt
% exit
% less -p advent searchthroughthis.txt
...
```